# Left/Right Sound Channels

Tags: android, google-tv

I am trying to switch off left sound channel:

```
MediaPlayer mp; 

....

mp.setVolume(0.f, 1f);
```

On tablet it works correctly, but on google tv, sound lost not only from left channel, but from right channel too. Help! Any ideas would be helpful. Thank you.

Update:
On this forum http://www.googletvforum.org/forum/logitech-revue/375-audio-problems-logitech-revue.html in one of replies such message: "Logitech has not yet figured out how to pipe multichannel audio thru hdmi.you have to use the optical output. Which is ok."

Comment: Perhaps your google tv box is cabled with only the Left channel actually connected to a speaker.

Comment: Google tv box is cabled to TV with HDMI cable

Comment: It's entirely possible that some part of the multimedia framework / audio HAL is ignoring the right volume and setting a single volume based on the left volume. I've seen such code on some platforms.  Do you get the same result if you do  mp.setVolume(1f, 0.f);  ?

Comment: I tried mp.setVolume(1f, 0.f) - sound did not lost.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684352/volume-channels/13707872#13707872

I have answered on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684352/volume-channels/13707872#13707872